# invoking java web service with C# client

Tags: c#, java, .net, asp.net, c#-3.0

How to invoking java web service(WSDL) with c# client (web application).Java web service methods is proxy.object will be created in client C#.Then how to call that proxy method in c# client? how to test that java web service in c# client side ?

Answer (score 2):

If the web service is a WSDL, you can test it using WcfTestClient utility that comes with .NET Framework. Go to .NET Command Prompt and type wcftestclient.. Here you can "Add Service" and type the full URL of the web service. You can even invoke the methods from here..

For consuming the web service, you can add web reference in your C# project which will create the proxy for you. In your program you will instantiate the proxy and call the method you need.